# Spring boot connection with non-local database

Tags: spring, database-connection

[i create a spring boot project with a local database and the connection work correctly :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEIJm.jpg)

```
# DATASOURCE setting:
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/t_anomalies
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
# JPA :
spring.jpa.database=MYSQL
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.strategy=-
strategy=strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

but now i put my database in a web server
i changed all the configuration (host,root,password) but i always received this message "Communications link failure"

```
# DATASOURCE setting:
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://newhost3:3306/t_anomalies
spring.datasource.username=newroot
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
# JPA :
spring.jpa.database=MYSQL
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.strategy=-
strategy=strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Comment: Can you telnet to remote mysql?

Comment: Maybe you have a stacktrace to show ?

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

Answer (score 0):

what are you using in 'newhost3' host name. verify connectivity with that host first.

Comment: i tested the new host with a php file and its work !

Comment: Verify it based on my.cnf of MySQL DB.

Comment: if not worked please have a look at 
 this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865538/solving-a-communications-link-failure-with-jdbc-and-mysql)

Comment: the application find the host but can not connect to it

Comment: i think that the problem is from the port